# Silverlight Grid does not fill

Tags: silverlight, prism

I have Border control defined like so:

```
<Border Background="Azure" Grid.Row="2">
    <ContentControl Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Regions:RegionManager.RegionName="MainContent" />
</Border>
```

I can see Azure background in whole area

Now I inject my view into this ContentControl (it's PRISM). View looks like this..

```
<toolkit:BusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}">
        <Grid Margin="10" DataContext="{Binding}"
                infBehaviors:RegionPopupBehaviors.CreatePopupRegionWithName="ViewPopup"
                infBehaviors:RegionPopupBehaviors.ContainerWindowStyle="{StaticResource PopupStyle}">
            <!--Define rows in a grid-->
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!--Define columns in a grid-->
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="65" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Now when I place new UserCOntrol on top of my Grid - I expect it to cover whole "Azure" area. But I only see overlay with size of my data entry form. It seems that second grid does not "fill" ContentControl - only takes as much space as needed. How do I force it to fill? I set Auto column and row - thinking they will stretch but no..

EDIT:
Screenshot from Silverlight Spy.. It shows that ContentControl from Shell covers whole area but grid inside totally ignores my "*" sizes. Also it does work in design mode - it stretches to whole design area...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have HorizontalContentAlignment and VerticalContentAlignment of the ContentControl set to Stretch. ^_^

e.g.

```
<Border Background="Azure" Grid.Row="2">
    <ContentControl HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
    Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Regions:RegionManager.RegionName="MainContent" />
</Border>
```

Comment: +1 just for being polite (and having a correct answer helps too :))